# How to stop blanking screen although I am active on Ubuntu Karmic on old IBM Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, ubuntu-9.10, power-management, fluxbox

How to stop blanking screen although I am active on Ubuntu Karmic on old IBM Laptop 600E?

After some time of working on the machine the screen goes blank. When I hit ESC on the built-in keyboard (not on the attached USB keyboard where I work) it comes back and everything works fine until the next screen-blanking.

I suspect it is some power management issue.

When I use an old keyboard that has a ps2 connector it does not happen.

So my guess is that the usb keyboard does not update the power management timer that detects when the session was last used?

I am using fluxbox window manager.

I do not want to disable power management because it is nice that the fan only works at the necessary speed (the fan speed is regulated which I can hear) But I could disable power management for testing purposes.

Comment: does the answer of Janne solved your problem? does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `xset -dpms`?